# Angular2 Routing redirect with routeParams

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a way to access the routerParams in the redirecTo-Statement?

I want to pass the orderId of the 'Order' route to the 'OrderDashboard' route but I can't figure out what to write instead of `???`

If I replace `???` with `3` all works fine (in case the user only is intrested in order number 3 ;-) )

`{path: '/:orderId', name: 'Order', redirectTo: ['OrderDashboard', {orderId:???}]}
 {path: '/:orderId/dashboard', name: 'OrderDashboard'}`

Answer (score 6):

Late to party but anyway,

I couldn't find any reference for accesing the `routeParams` at the time of `router.config`,
But still you can achieve the same behaviour by using one of these techniques

---

**1. Defining two routes using `Same Component`**

*(not exactly same as url will be different in address bar)*

```ts
{path: '/:orderId', name: 'Order', component: OrderDashboard}
{path: '/:orderId/dashboard', name: 'OrderDashboard', component: OrderDashboard}
```

**2. Using a disposable component as proxy**

```ts
{path: '/:orderId', name: 'Order', component: OnlyToRedirect}
{path: '/:orderId/dashboard', name: 'OrderDashboard', component: OrderDashboard}
```

```ts
export class OnlyToRedirect{
  constructor(routeParams: RouteParams, router: Router){
    router.navigate(['OrderDashboard', {orderId: routeParams.params}])
  }
}
```

Hope this works :)